# Intializing a list to contain dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How do I create an empty list in R, which I can later populate with dataframes? Would this be possible if I don't know the dimensions of the dataframe?
For example I want to do this: ​combined is a dataframe
and year_wave is an array containing 6 strings.
I want empty_list[1] to be s subset of the dataset combined that contains only those columns containing the string in year_wave[1]

```
empty_list[1]<-select(combined,contains(year_wave[1]))
```

Comment: Maybe: `empty_list <- list()` and then `empty_list[1] <- list(select(combined,contains(year_wave[1])))`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an empty list of dataframes you could use the `replicate` and `data.frame` arguments. I have produced a reprex of this below.

```r
replicate(3,data.frame())
#> [[1]]
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

A more complete function to do what you want could be a use of the `map` function in the code block below. The map function applies a function to all elements of a list or array and so we can apply our selection criteria using each of the strings. This will return a list of the dataframes. (Note that in map arg 1 is the list we iterate over, arg 2 is the function we call and any additional arguments are wholly passed to the function)

```r
map(year_wave, ~(..2 %>% select(contains(.x)), combined  ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What are "..2" and ".x" referencing in your Map code? I have not come across "." usage in R in this way. Could you please clarify?

Comment: In the map function when you define your function the inputs use the other arguments you pass to map. The list passed to map can be referenced as `.x` and any additional arguments are passed as `.. 2` and `.. 3` etc.  In map the dots are essentially just part of the names of the arguments.

Comment: If Arg 2 in Map is a function, what function are you calling? Does the code block in Arg 2 just return a dataset? I'm not clear what  ..2 would mean - though I feel your strategy is viable. Just very terse!

Comment: Essentially the function that is called is:

`
function(.x, ..2) {
 return(
  ..2 %>%
    select(contains(.x))
)
}
`

`~` notation is the way of defining a function in an argument to another function used in r

Yes the funciton does just return a dataset